# Is it possible to add a network interface to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Server Installer

Tags: server, usb, dell, xps, dock

I am currently trying to setup an unattended usb installer for my company (using ks and preseed) using Ubuntu 14.04.3 Server LTS.  We purchased the Dell XPS 13 (9343) (no onboard nic) with the Dell D3100 dock.  During the installation process, the usb dock's NIC is not detected.  However, after the install, I can go into `/etc/network/interfaces` and add `usb0` to the list, which will then allow me to bring the nic up.  It is important that I have `usb0` detected during initial setup so our local repo/packages can be included during the install process. `lo` is the only interface listed.

Things I have tried:

- including `d-i netcfg/choose_interface select usb0` in preseed
- including `netcfg/choose_interface=usb0` in kernel options (appended)

and much much more that have failed to work.

It seems like no matter what I try, I cannot get his to work.  I have been working on this for days.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  It has been a long day, and I'm just sure I'm leaving out important details, if you need any information, please let me know.

Comment: It's possible the setup kernel doesn't have modules for the USB NIC. Does a live Ubuntu detect the NIC?

Comment: Thank you for adjusting my formatting muru, I appreciate it :)

Comment: I did try ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso in the beginning, but switched to server due to constant issues with my preseed file.  I will switch back and try again.

Comment: ok, the desktop installer installs usb0, however, my preseed file does not work with it.  here is my preseed:

Comment: @Muru, The desktop live CD does indeed find usb0.  What is the difference between the Desktop Live CD and the Ubuntu 14.04 Server installer(x64 for both)? (also, my preseed file does not work with the Desktop installer).

Comment: I'm guessing here that the kernel in the Desktop ISO might have more modules enabled at boot. No, Ubiquity doesn't support a lot of options. You might try creating a custom server ISO with the kernel of the desktop version.